# How can i dump all PHP variables in current scope?

Tags: php, debugging, variables, session-variables

I need this for debugging purposes and need to dump all variables. Is there a way to get all variables? and is there any way to trace all calls after script ends? without changing my code. Note that i can't use xdebug or anything installable because my script is runnign on a host.

Comment: You can't change your code and you can't use an external tool?

Comment: I think he meant he can't change the way the variables are defined or another hackish solution like that

Comment: Yeha, and i just thought that php have something for my need, cause php always have something. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) function within PHP.

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of
>   all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined
>   variables, within the scope that get_defined_vars() is called.

Comment: Thank you! I swear I have looked for this before couldn't find it

Comment: @RobB How can we filter current method and see only current method's local variables and arguments? (local scope)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php).

```
<?php
    $a = 12;
    $b = "foo";
    $bar = "test";
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_defined_vars());
?>
```